# Explanation needed about HEAP and STACK when declaring threads for class members inside a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, heap-memory, stack-memory

Let's just get to it with the code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class something {
public:
    void some_function() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            cout << 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        something something_class;
        thread start(&something::some_function, &something_class);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This won't work, and that's basically because the something_class variable is getting freed at the end of the loop while the thread is using it, which will cause a nasty error.

Using dynamic allocation isn't better, because the allocated memory won't be freed unless we do so and we simply don't know when to do so...

We can probably solve this by declaring global variables, vectors, or something. But that's not good either, especially if we have a big program made out of a big number of classes and functions that should run all together.

**What's the solution here?** I really do not know, all I can think of is 
declaring vectors and global variables to solve this, but it wouldn't be right because I'm going to need a lot of them.

Comment: 'The allocated memory won't be freed unless we do so and we simply don't know when to do so' - sure you do - delete it at the end of the thread function.

Comment: But you do know when you can free the allocated memory - when the thread is finished.

Comment: Well I wanted to try what everyone mentioned since, logically, it should work but the problem is that, now, there's another problem; the thread is causing an abort when it finishes doing everything, why's that? I'm using the exact same code that I shared in the main question but I'm using dynamic allocation for the class this time.

Comment: I believe what I just commented was solved by detaching the thread, so what I'm basically doing to make this work is starting a thread with a pointer that leads to the instance of the class, detaching the thread, and making sure that the thread would delete the allocated memory pointed by that passed pointer. Is that the right way?

Comment: @MarioAda sounds good to me:)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a something instance with new, create the thread with its pointer as a parameter, let the thread delete it at the end of the thread function when it's finished with it.

No need for any massive panic/drama with vectors, join etc.

Comment: So you're saying that I can basically pass the pointer as an argument to my thread and then make the thread delete that allocated memory? This sounds like a delete this when we're not using threads. Anyways I will try that out when I get back from work.

Comment: Yes. that's exactly it.  It's not 'delete this' - the thread is one entity, the something is another.  Creating an object instance, (op. new), in one thread, signaling, (either as a thread creation argument or by later use of a P-C queue), the instance pointer to another thread and deleting it in that thread is an absolutely normal and common means of inter-thread comms.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (true)
{
    something something_class;
    thread start(&something::some_function, &something_class);
    start.detach();
}
```

I presume that for this case, the thread can proceed independently until it finishes on its own terms.  Otherwise, you would need to call

```
start.join();
```

but then invoking threads at all would be pretty pointless.  A third possibility would be to store threads as you mentioned and `join` them at a later time if/when synchronization was needed.

Comment: Thank you too, I will try to use detach and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

1. If the thread should be working independently from the rest of the program, and maybe even survive when the rest of the program exits, you could [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) it.
2. The normal case is that you store the thread somewhere, for example in a `std::vector`, and when you're done you tell the threads to exit (how to do this is another question) and then you [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the thread.

Comment: 2 isn't an option but 1 sounds like it, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MarioAda Be careful not to call `exit` or plainly `return` from the `main` function then, as that will end the process *and* all threads, including those that are detached. You need to use a platform-dependent function to exit the main thread, like e.g. [`pthread_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) on POSIX systems like OSX and Linux.